# Unexpected Error message from WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have one wcf webservice deployed on server. In case of an exception the error message behaves like code is getting executed from local machine. For example the below error message indicates the local machine folder where actual code is stored. for example "C:\initpub...". Why i am getting this error on server. Any suggestion?

> Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Trace:
>   Server stack trace:
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>   at Domain.ExternalAccount.ExternalAccount.InsertExternalAccountWithPositions(ExternalAccountWithPositionsInParam
>   request)
>   at Domain.ExternalAccount.ExternalAccountClient.InsertExternalAccountWithPositions(ExternalAccountWithPositionsInParam
>   request) in
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Site\Secure\finplanextsvc\NaviplanExternalServices\Domain\ExternalAccount.cs:line
>   3145
>   at NaviplanExternalServices.NaviplanExternalAccount.InsertExternalAccount(AccountType
>   acctType, ExternalPosition[] positions) in
>   **C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Site\Secure\finplanextsvc\NaviplanExternalServices\NaviplanExternalServices\Services\NaviplanExternalAccount.svc.cs:line 178**

Comment: Please enable WCF service logging by following instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original source path and line number are stored in the .pdb file that is built along with your application. If you also deploy the .pdb with your .dll, then you get these in your stack traces. That is the default .net behavior, and is actually makes throwing an exception slower to execute if you have the .pdb in the deploy directory next to the .dll or .exe.  You can remove that detail from the error message by not deploying, or deleting the .pdb file.

Answer (score 1):

The source file location is compiled into the .pdb when you build the project. It always refers to the source path from where it was built.

Comment: Its not in the .dll, it is in the .pdb

Comment: @rally25rs: You're right it's in the .pdb and not the .dll. My bad, it's updated now.